# How do I disable Google Fonts on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-font-api

I'm loading a Google Font in my `head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic" type="text/css" />
```

I want to disable this on mobile browsers to improve performance on slow Internet connections. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: I think, you could solve opposite task: enable google fonts only for non-mobile browsers.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or invites discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you ,you can separate it by adding media attribute

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/best-way-to-call-a-mobile-only-stylesheet/41310/3

Comment: Here is my media attributes
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" />

like this may be this can help

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic"; type="text/css" media="handheld" />